# Cant create foreign keys in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

- Created two tables emp_table and dept_table
- Cannot seem to add multiple foreign keys via ALTER keyword.

**emp_table**

```
-- Creating employee table
CREATE TABLE emp_table(
emp_id INT,
first_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(20),
job_id VARCHAR(10),
salary INT,
manager_id INT,
dept_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY(emp_id));
```

**dept_table**

```
-- Creating department table
CREATE TABLE dept_table(
dept_id INT,
dept_name VARCHAR(40),
location VARCHAR(20),
manager_id INT,
relocation_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY(dept_name));
```

**Trying to add foreign keys(FAILURE HERE)**

```
-- Adding foreign keys
ALTER TABLE dept_table
ADD FOREIGN KEY (dept_id) REFERENCES emp_table(dept_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
ADD FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES emp_table(manager_id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Comment: "FAILURE HERE" sounds like there is an error message you want to share?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the first table, try to form primary key  as composite key, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_table(
emp_id INT,
first_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(20),
job_id VARCHAR(10),
salary INT,
manager_id INT,
dept_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY(emp_id, manager_id));
```